# Checking for new data in background

Tags: android, xamarin

What is the recommended approach for checking for new data regardless if the app is in the foreground or background?  I am wondering which Android API people are typically using to do this.  There seems to be a few ways to achieve my goal, and I want to make sure I'm on the right path.

I have something put together which uses `AlarmManager.SetInexactRepeating()` to call an `IntentService` which does the sync and inserts/updates data in the database.  This works while the app is in the foreground and background, but if I force stop the app then I keep seeing "Unfortunately,  has stopped working" messages when the AlarmManager alarm would've triggered.  In this case, I only care about checking for new data only when the app is running in the foreground or background.

My first thought is to detect when the app is force closed, and stop the alarm, but that does not seem possible.  So I am asking here, is my approach wrong?  If so, which approach is used to perform some periodic task regardless if the phone is in the foreground or background? The problem with the AlarmManager solution I am using is the alarms continue to fire even when the app is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your idea is to check if your API has new data and perform a background sync to your local database or other data storage, I think you would like to take a look at this:

[Creating a Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

[Running a Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html)

The Sync adapter is the recommended way of achieving this in Android. The pros of using it are multiple:

- Optimisations out of the box - the OS bundles calls, uses the most appropriate windows to run the sync adapter at a minimal bandwidth and battery cost
- The lifecycle of your background sync component is managed internally by the OS
- Observers can be notified when data has been changed so the UI can be updated easily
- Multiple ways of running the sync - at intervals, automatically with the OS message to keep TCP/IP connections open or on demand

However, implementing this requires some things, that can cause a bit of a pain at first:

- It is mandatory that the adapter works with a `ContentProvider`
- Sync Adapters use Account for authentication. If this is not needed, a Stub has to be provided

Answer (score 2):

For backgrounding on Android usually you use even a Service that can run alone and independently from the App or a Bounded service that takes and returns data from the App. A complete reference on backgrounding can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_1_introduction_to_backgrounding_in_android/)

Answer (score 1):

Using a Service is the right way to go. Have your app start the Service and it will continue running while the app is in the foreground or the background. Then, if you want to kill the Service when your app closes, you could just call `stopService(yourServiceIntent);` from the `onDestroy()` override in your app's activity. That should effectively shut down the service when the app closes.

So some sample code of how this works (taken from the [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) docs)...

The Service (just Logs a message every 1 second for 60 seconds):

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    // Handler that receives messages from the thread
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60*1000;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(1000);
                        Log.d("SERVICE", "The service is still running.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }
}
```

And in your activity you would do something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent serviceIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Does this service stay running when the app is force closed by the user or OS?  That's is what I'm trying to solve.  The IntentService called by AlarmManager keeps running until reboot.  I only want to run my periodic background task while the app is running in foreground or background.

Comment: @Trevor Balcom - Yes, this solution will allow the service to run while the app is running (in the foreground OR background), but will shut down the service when the app is closed by the user or the OS. Additionally, you want to make sure and return START_NOT_STICKY from your onStartCommand() method in your service so that if the OS shuts the service down, it won't be automatically restarted.