# update UI on new API data from Observable

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-recyclerview

I'm too newbie to handle this by myself. I have a method where some API data is stored in an Observable and I'm trying to fire this event every 60 seconds. I'm doing this because I want to provide the recyclerView with actual data. If new data has arrived from the API, the *recyclewView* should refresh.

This is the method where I get the data from the API:

```java
fun getHead(status : String , wenr : Long, test : Boolean) {
        view.onShowDialog("")
        val headResponseObservable: Observable<List<WeKopf>> = apiService.getWEKopf(status, wenr, test) // an action must be done each time when a property’s value changes.
        Observable.interval(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap<Any> { n -> headResponseObservable }
            .repeat()
            .subscribe()
        subscribe(headResponseObservable, this, mainScheduler)
    }
```

The subscribe-method looks like this:

```java
    protected fun <T> subscribe(observable: Observable<T>, observer: Observer<T>, scheduler : Scheduler) {
        observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(observer)
    }
```

The problem is that the Observable emits the data to the Observer only once. After that, the UI doesn't refresh on it's own.

```java
   override fun onComplete() {
        view.onHideDialog()
    }

    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
        addToCompositeDisposable(d)
    }

    override fun onNext(t: List<WeKopf>) {
        view.onHideDialog()
        view.displayHeads(t)
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        view.onHideDialog()
        view.onError("Error getting supplier head: " + e.message)
    }
```

How can I extend the Observer to react event-driven when new data from the Observable is emitted? I'm looking for something similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32791251/12083845), that will refresh the recyclewView only.

At the moment, I'm able to refresh the UI only if I **manually** call my own `getHead`-method over and over again.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood your question `getHead()` should be called once, right? In this case I'll offer you to simplify your code this way:

```
fun getHead(status: String, wenr: Long, test: Boolean): Observable<List<WeKopf>> =
        Observable.interval(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap { apiService.getWEKopf(status, wenr, test) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .also {
                view.onShowDialog("")
            }
```

And then you should subscribe to the result of your `getHead()` like that:

```
getHead(status, wenr, test).subscribe(observer)
```

By the way, don't forget to dispose your `Disposable` objects after all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Could you please tell me where should I make the subscription to the result of getHead()?

Comment: You are welcome :) You should subscribe right in the same place where `getHead()` is called. I think it's based on your business logic.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the modified `getHead`-method didn't work as expected. First of all, I wasn't able to subscribe to the result in the Activity where the method is called, without creating an Observable object and overriding it's methods first. `subscribe()` without parameters didn't work as well. And the recyclerView Adapter couldn't display the data on the UI - at least the View was empty in the UI. It doesn't matter how often the `getHead` method will be called. The recyclerView should update by itself in case new data came out from the API. Anyway, many thanks for your efforts. Boris

Comment: Hm. It's weird, because I've just tested my solution and it works. Could you please explain _"I wasn't able to subscribe to the result in the Activity where the method is called, without creating an Observable object and overriding it's methods first."_? In my solution the result of `getHead()` is `Observable<List<WeKopf>>` so you get Observable object and you able to subscribe your observer to it. What does your `apiService.getWEKopf(status, wenr, test)` return? And, talking about Android, which Scheduler do you provide for your `observeOn()` function?

Comment: Thank you for your time and for sharing your knowledge with me. I'm calling `ObserveOn(mainScheduler)` where `val mainScheduler: Scheduler`. I can try the solution on Monday, as soon as come back in the office and test the app on the hardware.

Comment: Glad to see you here again! Firstly, I'd propose to use ```implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'``` dependency, which has ```AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()``` to pass to ```observeOn()```. And, secondly, see you on Monday ;)

Comment: Your solution works as a charm. You made it happen! Thank you so much for all of your efforts. I admire your willingness to help others. Thanks a lot for giving me the opportunity to learn new things.:)

Comment: I'm so happy that it's was helpful and problem is finally solved! If you want, you can contact me directly via Telegram (same nickname) in the future. Would be great if I could help again (it's also significant experience for me) :)